# How to get the released date from a webpage?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
url = "http://www.padtube.com/Audio-Music-Editor/10-75359.html"
pageurl = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageurl)

for table in soup.select("table#product-quickfacts-table"):
    print table.find('meta',{'itemprop':'datePublished'})
```

When I run this code,it gives me this output:

```
<meta content="2012-03-01T00:00:00-05:00" itemprop="datePublished"/>
```

How can I take only the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your line

```
print table.find('meta',{'itemprop':'datePublished'})

<meta content="2012-03-01T00:00:00-05:00" itemprop="datePublished"/>
```

returns the element meta containing the attribute `itemprop='datePublished'`. You simply want to access the `content` node of this xml element

```
print table.find('meta',{'itemprop':'datePublished'})['content']

2012-03-01T00:00:00-05:00
```

Comment: Can it be strip so that can take only 2012-03-01?